# Why is my output returning "None None" when creating a dict()?

Tags: python

I'm completing an exercise that requires me to create a `dict()` and figure out who has sent the greatest number of email messages. The correct output is supposed to be `cwen@iupui.edu 5` but my code is returning `None None`. Here is my code:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
        recipient = line.split()
        email = recipient[1]
        counts[email] = counts.get(email,0) + 1
            
maxcount = None
maxemail = None
for key,value in counts.items():
    if maxcount is None or value> maxcount:
        maxemail = key
        maxcount = value

print(maxemail, maxcount)
```

I understand that my output is returning `None None` because there's nothing in my dictionary, so where is my code going wrong? I've attempted to move around some lines within the for loop but received the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three lines below "continue" should be unindented. That is, should be at the same level as the "if" line before.